# Find an explicit formula for $I_n$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: fractals, affine-geometry

Let $b > 0$, $0 < a < 1$, and set $f(x) = ax + b$. Moreover, put
$I_0 = [0, b]$, $I_n = f^{◦n}(I_0)$, $n = 1, 2, \dots$
and
$$I = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty I_n.$$

1. Find an explicit formula for $I_n$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. The endpoints of In should be
   polynomial in powers of $a$. Use this to prove that $I$ is an interval. You may assume without
   proof that the length of this interval is finite. Let $\ell$ denote the length of $I$.

A picture of the question in case my formatting does not make sense [picutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBVOj.png).

Any help to even just get started with this question would be very much appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $f$ is a monotonically increasing, continuous function on the closed interval $[x,y]$. Then $f([x,y])=[f(x),f(y)]$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\,f\,$ is continuous and strictly increasing, and therefore, as suggested by Gary in his comment, we have

$$ I_1=f(I_0)=f([0,b])=[f(0),f(b)]=[b,ab+b]=[b,(a+1)b] $$

and similarly

$$ I_2=f(I_1)=f([b,(a+1)b])=[f(b),f((a+1)b)]=[(a+1)b,(a^2+a+1)b]. $$

Note that $I_0$ and $I_1$, as well as $I_1$ and $I_2$, are consecutive closed intervals, i.e. the right end of the first equals the left end of the second, so $I_0\cup I_1$ and $I_0\cup I_1\cup I_2$ are intervals.

The formulas above seem to suggest that in general one has

$$ I_n=[(a^{n-1}+\ldots+a+1)b,(a^n+a^{n-1}+\ldots+a+1)b], $$

which is very simple to prove by induction:

$$ I_{n+1}=f(I_n)=[(a(a^{n-1}+\ldots+a+1)b+b,a(a^n+a^{n-1}+\ldots+a+1)b+b]=\,
=[(a^n+\ldots+a+1)b,(a^{n+1}+\ldots+a+1)b]\qquad \text{q.e.d.}$$

For each $n\in\mathbb N$, the intervals $I_0,I_1,\ldots,I_n$ being consecutive, we have

$$ \bigcup_{k=0}^n I_k=[0,(a^n+\ldots+a+1)b]=\Big[0,\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}\,b\Big]. $$

Now it is easy to prove that

$$ I=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} I_n=\Big[0,\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}\,b\Big[=\Big[0,\frac{b}{1-a}\Big[. $$

Indeed, as the sequence $n\mapsto \frac{\displaystyle 1-a^n}{\displaystyle1-a}\,b\;$ is strictly increasing (being $0<a<1$) towards $\frac{\displaystyle b}{\displaystyle 1-a}$, it follows that

$$ x\in I \iff x\in I_\nu=\Big[0,\frac{1-a^{\nu+1}}{1-a}b\Big]\; \text{ for some } \nu\in\mathbb N \iff 0\leq x<\frac{\displaystyle b}{\displaystyle 1-a}. $$